# See total reputation for today only

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-graph

Jon Skeet seems to have a nice daily reputation tracker, but is there a way in *StackOverflow* to query the total reputation earned for today or yesterday alone?  The graph seems unable to limit data to today only, and there don't seem to be "today" and "yesterday" buttons under the reputation tab like I've seen on some screenshots to older questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Define "today". UTC or your time zone?

Comment: I would say UTC, since that's what the daily cap is defined against.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use the reputation graph. Use the envelope report or the reputation audit. Both of these will break down the sources of reputation, provide a total sum for the given time span, and also note any "denied" reputation from votes that occur after hitting the reputation cap.

You reach the envelope report by clicking on the envelope that is next to your username at the top of every page - it contains filters for "today" and "yesterday", and can also be scoped to longer periods of time up to 60 days. Be sure to pick the "reputation" tab explicitly, as the default view is only of the top 5 sources for the time period. This will show you the value for your displayed reputation.

The reputation audit is reached by going to `/reputation` on the site (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/reputation). It will show you the full breakdown of data by day, so you can scroll down to any particular day to see its info. Today traditionally being the latest day, this will be at the very bottom. This will show you the value for your *true* reputation, as deleted content does not get reflected in your reputation until you trigger a reputation recalc.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to the "envelope" next to your name, click on the Reputation tab and then click on "today" or "yesterday" it should show you the relevant number. (This is *not* the reputation tab of your publicly visible user profile.)

Comment: I love your daily rep tracker, don't get me wrong, was just looking for something built into SO.  Just started v2 of your book, btw - love it :)

Answer (score 4):

If you click on the envelope ([image: envelope]) next to your name you will get a nice activity report.  You can click on Today or Yesterday, and view reputation, replies or other stats.

Your url is:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/352552?Tab=Reputation&StartDate=2011-02-10&EndDate=2011-02-10